# TAB key space count in text widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

In `tkinter` library <kbd>Tab</kbd> puts +8 space into `Text()` widget.

How do I change number of spaces?

My `tkinter` code:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

txt = Text()
txt.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

.

Comment: You have to create a post for each library, the questions that ask the same for several libraries is off-topic and it will be more difficult to help you

Comment: when I run the code on my computer there is only a blank text box. are you saying that in the text box there are 8 tabs for you?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the Text widget? There are options specifically to deal with tabs and stabstops.

Comment: When we click [TAB] key in keybord it puts 8 or more spaces. I want to change it. Can I do it?

Comment: Bryan Oakley Thanks. I fund there. Text(tabs=`variable`) is works.

Comment: Are you asking how to literally insert four spaces, or are you asking how to set a tabstop that is 4 spaces wide? The tab key normally does _not_ insert 8 spaces. It inserts a single tab, and tab stops default to being 8 characters. Literally inserting 4 spaces is different than inserting a tab with a tabstop at 4 characters are completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this change to your code from
[Python/Tkinter: How to set text widget contents to the value of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957085/python-tkinter-how-to-set-text-widget-contents-to-the-value-of-a-variable)

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

txt = Text()
txt.pack()

def tab(arg):
    print("tab pressed")
    txt.insert(INSERT, " " * 4) #this number is where you set the amount of spaces to add per tab
    return 'break'

txt.bind("<Tab>", tab)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you this works and also Text(tabs=`var`) too.

Comment: Usually a tab is intended to line things up vertically, which will take a variable number of spaces depending on how many characters are to the left.

Comment: true but you could read the current line and adjust the insert accordingly